# Countdown Timer Linking Design Parts

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have some HTML and JavaScript, but this error appears:

[image]

I'm building a timer. This is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer">
        
    </div>
<script src="appCT.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript File1

```
export default class Timer {
    constructor(root){
        console.log(root);
        root.innerHTML = Timer.getHTML();

        this.el = {
            minutes: root.querySelector(".timer__part--minutes");
            seconds: root.querySelector(".timer__part--seconds");
            control: root.querySelector(".timer__btn--control");
            reset: root.querySelector(".timer__btn--reset");
        }

        console.log(this.el);
    }

    static getHTML(){
         return `
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--minutes">00</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part">:</span>
        <span class="timer__part timer__part--seconds">00</span>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--control timer__btn--start">
            <span class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="timer__btn timer__btn--reset">
            <span class="material-icons">timer</span>
        </button>` 
    }
}
```

JavaScript File 2

```
import Timer from "Timer.js";

new Timer{
    document.querySelector(".timer");
}
```

Css code

```
body{
    background: #dddd;
    margin: 24px;

}

.timer{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 24px 32px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: white;
}

.timer__part{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.timer__btn{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background: gray;
}

.timer__btn--control{
    background: steelblue;
}

.timer__btn--reset{
    background: red;
}
```

The code should be able to display the timer, and each HTML element should be linked with its respective part in the design. I've tried to change the type "attribute" of my script element to text/javascript, but it has not yielded fruits.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

**Your browser will not redirect to such an address.
1- I would recommend trying to work with localhost.
2- VSCode  [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)
And I found something maybe useful to you.**

["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).